# Drag and drop with Dragula on Angular

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, ng2-dragula

necessary to drag-and-drop the block using the Dragula library. Library version 1.5.0 is used.I get error `Angular: Can't bind to 'dragula' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.`. How to implement block dragging?

shared.module.ts:

```js
import {DragulaModule} from 'ng2-dragula/ng2-dragula';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...COMPONENTS,
    ...PAGES
  ],
  imports: [
    DragulaModule,
    ...
  ]
})

export class SharedModule {
}
```

item.component.html:

```html
<div [dragula]='"items"' [dragulaModel]="items.controls"  formArrayName="items">
  <input-container [formGroupName]="i"  *ngFor="let item of items.controls">
     <input formControlName="name"/>
  </input-container>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your module imports from:

```
imports: [
    DragulaModule,
    ...
  ]
```

into

```
imports: [
    DragulaModule.forRoot(),
    ...
  ]
```

and try to change reference from `import {DragulaModule} from 'ng2-dragula/ng2-dragula';` into `import { DragulaModule } from 'ng2-dragula';`

Also make sure in your component.ts you had already import:

```
import { DragulaService } from 'ng2-dragula';
```

and put:

```
@Component({..
   providers: [DragulaService]
....})
```